# Clean URL structure for php page without having a real page

Tags: php, json, url, search

I have a page where I am loading up a JSON file and matching data based on a users search.

The caveat however, is that I want to have really clean URLs for these results without actually making a new page for them. (For the life of me I don't know what the terminology for this is)

So when a user goes to website.com/names/adrian it will just land on /names/ and load the data based on "adrian".

Comment: You might be interested in using a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in your URL, or is that not "clean" enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with apache's rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(names\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_]+)$ names.php?name=$1
```

Add this to your .htaccess file
It will send example.com/names/aName as get request to names.php.

And you can get that with $_GET["name"]; in names.php

By the way, you can see regex result in here: https://regexr.com/415mq

Comment: This is very useful. What if I wanted to do a match for a phone number as well? So website.com/phone/123456789

Comment: @AdrianRodriguez Change `^(names\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_]+)$` regex with `^(phone\/[0-9]+)$` or you can use same regex and check if it is a phone number in php